# Squaring the difference of two Ranges passed into a function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am confused on the output and how to access each cell from the range in the for loop. For example if my range is from A1:J1, then my second range is from A2:J2, in my function how do I subtract then square and then out put that answer in the highlighted cells on excel.
I am very new to VBA and I am trying to help a friend.
[This is what my excel doc looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kik7h.png)
[This is the question I am given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upb7a.png)

Comment: Use the Cells property with row and column starting at 1

Comment: Your function does not seem to contain any executable code yet, beyond some variable definitions. This forum can help you troubleshoot an attempted answer, but is not here to create an answer for you. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Squaring Differences in a Two-Row Range

- This is one way how it could be handled.
- It will not do as the homework since it uses only one array for the range and it is 'polluted' with error handling, but it may shed some light on what you have to do.
- Test it to see if it does what you need.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function getDiffsSquared( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = getDiffsSquared
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Resize(2).Value
        Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(Data, 2))
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim c As Long
        For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Result(1, c) = (Data(2, c) - Data(1, c)) ^ 2
        Next c
        On Error GoTo clearError
        getDiffsSquared = Result
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Sub getSquareDiffsTEST()
    Const rgAddr As String = "A1:J2"
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range(rgAddr)
    rg.Resize(1).Offset(2).Value = getDiffsSquared(rg)
End Sub
```